# $\{0,1\}$-valued continuous functions on the Cantor set

Tags: cantor-set

Let $P$ be the ternary Cantor set. I need to determine all continuous functions $f:P\to \mathbb{F}_2$ where $\mathbb{F}_2=\{0,1\}$ is the finite field with two elements.

We know that $P$ is homeomorphic to the infinite product $\prod_{i=0}^\infty\mathbb{F}_2$. The projection $\pi_j$ to the $j$th component is of course a desired one. Also if we let the point-wise addition and production of functions $f,g:P\to\mathbb{F}_2$ by $(f+g)(x)=f(x)+g(x)$ and $(fg )(x)=f(x)g(x)$, then any product and addition of projections is also a continuous map.

It seems to me that all elements of $C(P,\mathbb{F}_2)$ are finite sums of production of projections, but I stuck!

Thanks for your helps.

Comment: Fix the typo in the third line. It's actually two.

Comment: @AvinashN Done. Thanks.

Comment: Also the "Contor" set in the first sentence should be a "Cantor" set

Comment: @celtschk Well by "the" Cantor set, I mean the classical Cantor set, which obtained by removing middle third interval in each step.

Comment: @Qurultay: I meant the spelling error “Contor” for “Cantor”. The placement of quotation marks is significant!

Comment: @celtschk Done. Thanks

Comment: Are you considering $\mathbb{F}_2$ with the discrete topology?

Comment: @GuidoA. Yes it is.

Comment: *Hint*: the open subgroups of $P=\mathbb{F}_2^{\mathbb{N}}$ are the finite-index subgroups.  So we know what the clopen sets look like, and hence what continuous functions there are.

Comment: @user10354138 +1. Thanks.

Comment: @user10354138 What is the relevance of open subgroups for this question?